# How can I check if a gzipped file is empty?

Tags: command-line, bash, gzip

Is there a quick way to check if a gzipped file is empty, or do I have to unzip it first?

example:

```
$ touch foo
$ if [ -s foo ]; then echo not empty; fi
$ gzip foo
$ if [ -s foo.gz ]; then echo not empty; fi
not empty
$ wc -l foo.gz
      1 foo.gz
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`gzip -l foo.gz | awk 'NR==2 {print $2}'` prints the size of the uncompressed data.

```
if LC_ALL=C gzip -l foo.gz | awk 'NR==2 {exit($2!=0)}'; then
  echo foo is empty
else
  echo foo is not empty
fi
```

Alternatively you can start uncompressing the data.

```
if [ -n "$(gunzip <foo.gz | head -c 1 | tr '\0\n' __)" ]; then
    echo "foo is not empty"
else
    echo "foo is empty"
fi
```

(If your system doesn't have `head -c` to extract the first byte, use `head -n 1` to extract the first line instead.)

Comment: I assume `LC_ALL=C` is there to ensure that gzip does not put in thousand separators in numbers so the field can be compared to zero?

Comment: @camh: It's more general paranoia when parsing formatted output from a command. It could be the number format, or that in some language there are two header lines, or many other things I just haven't thought of. In the case of gzip, I think nothing bad happens, but `LC_ALL=C` can't hurt.

Comment: The second alternative will fail if the file has data but does not have a newline; it also won't print the line as `read` is being invoked in a subshell (and `$line` is not propagated to the parent).

Comment: @ChrisDown Well spotted. Your fix isn't enough though (plus the way you wrote it is bash-only). If the file starts with a null byte, the shell (other than zsh) will see an empty string when it shouldn't. A pipe through `tr` fixes that.

Answer (score 4):

If by 'empty' you mean that the uncompressed file is 0 bytes, you could use `gzip --list foo.gz` to determine the size of the uncompressed file, it would require some parsing to automate it.  It looks something like this:

```
$ gzip --list foo.gz
         compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
                 24                   0   0.0% foo
```

Answer (score 2):

```
test -z $(gzip -cd foo.gz | head -c1) && echo "empty"
```

Or with `if`:

```
if [ -z $(gzip -cd foo.gz | head -c1) ]; then
  echo "empty"
fi
```

`zcat` is sometimes linked to `gunzip -c` or `gzip -cd`, if you want to use it as the shorter "form".

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the gzip file format only allows 32 bits for storing the original file size, so the number there is the size modulo 2^32.  Hence the size given by "gzip -l" is not a definitive test for emptiness.

Comment: Please make this a more complete answer by including an example of how you would approach a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the gzip file size is 51, it is empty. Whenever I added a char in a file and gzip the file, zipped file size begins to increase from 51.

However you can guarantee it with zcat. in gzip man:

> The uncompressed size is given as -1 for files not in gzip format,
> such as compressed .Z files. To get the uncompressed size for such a
> file, you can use:

```
zcat file.Z | wc -c
```